# Shell - Theme unchangeable - how to overcome sap bug

Tags: themes, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I have just deployed a `MasterDetailView` application in **SAP_Belize**.

The app is created from a freestyle template, where in the `flpSandbox.html` file I have defined the Theme to be: sap_belize.

When I run the app on the `WebIDE` I get the Theme as expected.

But when I deploy the app on the HCP, I get only the `sap_bluecrystal` Theme, even on the app itself, does someone understand this, or **is it even known to the SAP Community that this occurs** ?

Further, when I try to change the Theme on the Shell to which I am brought, (since the freestyle templates are configured to be in app - in launchpad) it tells me that the Theme is already set as wanted (sap_belize) but it is still using the bluecrystal Theme, as you can see on the picture.

What I find even more troubling is that you cannot even modify the Theme from the settings window which is shown in the Picture.

[image: Shell - Theme settings]

here is the manifest file:

```
{
"_version": "1.4.0",
"sap.app": {
    "id": "charm",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "dataSources": {
        "mainService": {
            "uri": "/HANAMDC4/APPAPP/XS_CHANGEREQUESTS_DATA.xsodata/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/XS_CHANGEREQUESTS_DATA.xsodata/metadata.xml"
            }
        }
    },
    "sourceTemplate": {
        "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponent",
        "version": "0.0.0"
    },
    "crossNavigation": {
        "inbounds": {}
    }
},
"sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
        "icon": "sap-icon://detail-view",
        "favIcon": "",
        "phone": "",
        "phone@2": "",
        "tablet": "",
        "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
        "sap_belize"
    ]
},
"sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "charm.view.App",
        "type": "XML",
        "id": "app"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.42.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {
                "minVersion": "1.42.0"
            },
            "sap.m": {
                "minVersion": "1.42.0"
            },
            "sap.ushell": {
                "minVersion": "1.42.0"
            },
            "sap.collaboration": {
                "minVersion": "1.42",
                "lazy": true
            }
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "charm.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "": {
            "dataSource": "mainService",
            "preload": true
        }
    },
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "charm.view",
            "controlId": "idAppControl",
            "controlAggregation": "detailPages",
            "bypassed": {
                "target": [
                    "master",
                    "notFound"
                ]
            },
            "async": true
        },
        "routes": [
            {
                "pattern": "categmaster",
                "name": "categmaster",
                "target": [
                    "categDetail",
                    "categmaster"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "master",
                "name": "master",
                "target": [
                    "object",
                    "master"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "uploadCollection",
                "name": "uploadCollection",
                "target": "uploadCollection"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "CHANGE_REQUEST_LIST/{objectId}",
                "name": "object",
                "target": [
                    "master",
                    "object"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "approvedmaster",
                "name": "approvedmaster",
                "target": [
                    "approvedDetail",
                    "approvedmaster"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "rejectedmaster",
                "name": "rejectedmaster",
                "target": [
                    "rejectedDetail",
                    "rejectedmaster"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "allmaster",
                "name": "allmaster",
                "target": [
                    "allDetail",
                    "allmaster"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "categDetail",
                "name": "categDetail",
                "target": [
                    "categmaster",
                    "categDetail"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "approvedDetail",
                "name": "approvedDetail",
                "target": [
                    "approvedmaster",
                    "approvedDetail"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "rejectedDetail",
                "name": "rejectedDetail",
                "target": [
                    "rejectedmaster",
                    "rejectedDetail"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "allDetail",
                "name": "allDetail",
                "target": [
                    "allmaster",
                    "allDetail"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "targets": {
            "categmaster": {
                "viewName": "CategMaster",
                "viewLevel": 1,
                "viewId": "categmaster",
                "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
            },
            "uploadCollection": {
                "viewName": "upload.Page",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "approvedmaster": {
                "viewName": "ApprovedMaster",
                "viewLevel": 2,
                "viewId": "approvedMaster",
                "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
            },
            "rejectedmaster": {
                "viewName": "RejectedMaster",
                "viewLevel": 2,
                "viewId": "rejectedmaster",
                "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
            },
            "allmaster": {
                "viewName": "AllMaster",
                "viewLevel": 2,
                "viewId": "allmaster",
                "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
            },
            "categDetail": {
                "viewName": "CategDetail",
                "viewLevel": 3,
                "viewId": "Detail"
            },
            "approvedDetail": {
                "viewName": "ApprovedDetail",
                "viewLevel": 3,
                "viewId": "approvedDetail"
            },
            "rejectedDetail": {
                "viewName": "RejectedDetail",
                "viewLevel": 3,
                "viewId": "RejectedDetail"
            },
            "allDetail": {
                "viewName": "AllDetail",
                "viewLevel": 3,
                "viewId": "AllDetail"
            },
            "master": {
                "viewName": "Master",
                "viewLevel": 2,
                "viewId": "master",
                "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
            },
            "object": {
                "viewName": "Detail",
                "viewId": "detail",
                "viewLevel": 3
            },
            "categobject": {
                "viewName": "CategDetail",
                "viewId": "detail",
                "viewLevel": 3
            },
            "detailObjectNotFound": {
                "viewName": "DetailObjectNotFound",
                "viewId": "detailObjectNotFound"
            },
            "detailNoObjectsAvailable": {
                "viewName": "DetailNoObjectsAvailable",
                "viewId": "detailNoObjectsAvailable"
            },
            "notFound": {
                "viewName": "NotFound",
                "viewId": "notFound"
            }
        }
    }
},
"sap.platform.hcp": {
    "uri": "webapp",
    "_version": "1.1.0"
}
```

}

html file : flpSandbox.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Change and Request Management</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap the unified shell in sandbox mode for standalone usage.

        The renderer is specified in the global Unified Shell configuration object "sap-ushell-config".

        The fiori2 renderer will render the shell header allowing, for instance,
        testing of additional application setting buttons.

        The navigation target resolution service is configured in a way that the empty URL hash is
        resolved to our own application.

        This example uses relative path references for the SAPUI5 resources and test-resources;
        it might be necessary to adapt them depending on the target runtime platform.
        The sandbox platform is restricted to development or demo use cases and must NOT be used
        for productive scenarios.
    -->
    <script>
        window["sap-ushell-config"] = {
            defaultRenderer : "fiori2",
            renderers: {
                fiori2: {
                    componentData: {
                        config: {
                            search: "hidden"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            applications: {
                "ChangeandRequestManagement-display": {
                    additionalInformation: "SAPUI5.Component=charm",
                    applicationType: "URL",
                    url: "../",
                    description: "Approval app for ChaRM",
                    title: "Change and Request Management"
                }
            }
        };
    </script>

    <script src="../test-resources/sap/ushell/bootstrap/sandbox.js" id="sap-ushell-bootstrap"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap the UI5 core library -->
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ushell, sap.collaboration, sap.m, sap.ui.layout"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-frameOptions='allow'> // NON-SECURE setting for testing environment
    </script>

    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            // initialize the ushell sandbox component
            sap.ushell.Container.createRenderer().placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>

</head>

<!-- UI Content -->
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
```

neo_app.json:

```
    {
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/webapp/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/webapp/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/HANAMDC4",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "HANAMDC4"
      },
      "description": "HANA_MDC_4"
    }
  ],
  "cacheControl": [
    {
      "directive": "private",
      "maxAge": 0,
      "path": "**.html"
    },
    {
      "directive": "private",
      "maxAge": 0,
      "path": "sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json"
    },
    {
      "directive": "public",
      "maxAge": 31536000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you please show your manifest file?

Comment: Yes, i have just included it

Comment: can you show your index.html file? (testFLPService.html)

Comment: Done.
Thank you Andrii

Comment: well, looks ok so far. Can you show your "neo-app.json" file?

Comment: Yes, i have just updated the text

Comment: Thank you Andrii, gues SAP solved it

Answer (score 0):

HAS BEEN SOLVED - WORKS FINE NOW
guess it was a intern SAP problem, they fixed it